# sql - Request that handle unlimited parent

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am currently working on PostgreSQL having 2 data tables, LU (Logistical Unit) and Item.

An item is in a LU and a LU can be in another LU.

```
Item (id integer, name string, Luid integer references LU.id)
LU (id integer, name string, parentLuId references LU.id (can be null)
```

A a parentLuId can be null if there is no LU into it.

I want to display all the LU that contains a specific Item, even if this item is in the children of the children of this LU.

this example set of data

```
LU(1,"A",NULL)
LU(2,"B",NULL)
LU(3,"C",NULL)
LU(4,"D",NULL)
LU(5,"E",1)
LU(6,"F",5)


Item(1,"baloon",6)
Item(2,"baloon",2)
Item(4,"pencil",4)
Item(5,"baloon",3)
Item(6,"baloon",2)
Item(7,"baloon",6)
```

Selecting the UL that contains a baloon should display **ABCEF** because **D** doesnt contains a baloon.
**A** and **E** contains a baloon because they are parents from **F** that contains baloons.

I want to be able to handle an unlimited number of parents.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL recursive parent/child query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54907495/postgresql-recursive-parent-child-query)

Comment: I have trouble with recursivity and I am not using a table to do the association like in your example.

Comment: OK, close request retracted....  But could you add your table definitions (DDL) and a small set of example data ?

Comment: Because you added LU.parentLuId, which has a reference to LU.id, which (can) also have another LU.parentid, which ...... you NEED to have some recursivity

Comment: Based on the text you shared above, I have created a [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=42eb94e2657e7ce6943f8a40d4dff73c)  (which outputs `ABCEF`)

Comment: @Luuk, it is based on coincidence IMHO. Item.id = lu.id is irrelevant (item.id is primary key for item table and not related to LU, no?).

Comment: @CetinBasoz: That;s why I based it on the text, not on the data he gave .... 

Comment: @Luuk, I mean what if item ids started from 20. I don't see where in text he is after doing an inner join on item.id = lu.id.

Comment: @CetinBasoz: i forgot to say that you are right! But I do not know a different way of getting the requested `ABCEF` out of the given text...  Maybe Pierrem will share his idea ?

Comment: @Luuk, oh it is a recursive query to get the ancestors. If what you mean is to get it pure text as ABCEF, simply sort the result on Name and use string_agg(). Check the fiddle in my reply.

Comment: @CetinBasoz: He (=OP) "I have trouble with recursivity" ...  but I will  mark your answer as usefull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a recursive query with ancestors. ie:

```
with RECURSIVE ancestors AS (
    SELECT Id,
           Name,
           parentLuId
    FROM Lu
    WHERE exists(select * from item i where i.Luid = LU.id and i.Name = 'baloon')
    UNION
    SELECT d.Id,
           d.Name,
           d.parentLuId
    FROM Lu 
             inner JOIN ancestors c ON c.parentLuId = d.Id
)
SELECT *
FROM ancestors;
```

Here is [DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b2beebf2faa77cb890b103cabd486c95)